# Difference between UnicastSubject and ReplaySubject in rxjava

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, reactive

From [RxJava JavaDocs Link](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/)

Says:
**ReplaySubject** : *Subject that buffers all items it observes and replays them to any Observer that subscribes.*

**UnicastSubject** : *A Subject variant which buffers events until a single Subscriber arrives and replays them to it and potentially switches to direct delivery once the Subscriber caught up and requested an unlimited amount.*

Ps. one of the differences I have got over implementing both is UnicastSubject can have only one Subscriber(as proves name Unicast), whereas ReplaySubject can have as many.

Comment: Also, `UnicastSubject` can free internal buffer once single subscriber is subscribed, while `ReplaySubject` has to hold that buffer, either bounded (through size or TTL limiting factories) or unbounded - it has no `clear()` like method, so the only way that memory gets freed is when `ReplaySubject` is GCed.

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov agree!